# how to delete completely a google calendar instance via goggle-apps-script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I searched for the answer here (StackOverflow) but without success.

I need to delete an entire **calendar** in the **Goggle Calendar** via **Google-apps-script.**
It is exactly what I need. Delete at once a Calendar and consequently all the events that were associated with this respective calendar. After that, My intent is to create a new Calendar from scratch having only the events that matter.
My main goal is to synchronize all the appointments that exist in my system with the google calendar application. I think it is a direct way to reach there.  I am open to new suggestions as well.
Any help on this subject will be hugely appreciated.

Comment: The script you want is `CalendarApp.getCalendarById("###calendarId###").deleteCalendar()`? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#deletecalendar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Delete Calendar

```
function deleteCalendar() {
  CalendarApp.getCalendarById('calid').deleteCalendar();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the correct answer.
The answer labeled as 1 is also correct.

Answer (score 1):

About the method for permanently deleting Calendar using Google Apps Script, there are 2 methods.

### Pattern 1:

Uses Calendar Service (CalendarApp). The sample script is as follows.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const calendarId = "###"; // Please set the calendar ID you want to delete.
  CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId).deleteCalendar();
}
```

#### Pattern 2:

Uses Calendar API. The sample script is as follows. In this case, [please enable Calendar API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```js
function myFunction() {
  const calendarId = "###"; // Please set the calendar ID you want to delete.
  Calendar.Calendars.remove(calendarId);
}
```

#### Note:

- **When this script is run, the calendar is permanently deleted. So please be careful about this. When you test this, please use a sample Calendar.**
- When the primary calendar is deleted, an error occurs. So, if you want to delete all events from the primary calendar, it is required to delete all events using a script instead of deleting the calendar. Please be careful about this.
- When you want to delete a lot of events from a Calendar using Google Apps Script, this report might be useful. [Ref](https://github.com/tanaikech/Managing-A-Lot-Of-Google-Calendar-Events-using-Batch-Requests-with-Google-Apps-Script)

#### References:

- [deleteCalendar()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#deleteCalendar())
- [Calendars: delete](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/calendars/delete)
- [Managing A Lot Of Google Calendar Events using Batch Requests with Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tanaikech/Managing-A-Lot-Of-Google-Calendar-Events-using-Batch-Requests-with-Google-Apps-Script)